# "Feature flags: `classic_mirrored_queue_version`: required feature flag not enabled! It must" error when starting RMQ server in Ubuntu

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am following https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-quick-start-cloudsmith this section to install RMQ on **ubuntu** but I am unable to start the rmq-server. I get the following error. I didn't add source list file as I think it is extra. i am following the cloudsmith one.

Error in jounralctl -xe

[image]

Kindly tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for an Ubuntu 20 fresh installation and had to reset the `/var/lib/rabbitmq` folder to fix:

```bash
# probably not needed since it won't start ...
sudo systemctl stop rabbitmq-server

cd /var/lib
sudo mv rabbitmq rabbitmq.broken
sudo mkdir rabbitmq
sudo chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq rabbitmq
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

And it should spin up properly with a new configuration. You can probably remove the `/var/lib/rabbitmq.broken` folder afterwards.